# C# emulate xmlhttprequest and get json response

Tags: c#, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

How emulate xmlhttprequest and get json response?

Here Answer:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.1.7
Date: Fri, 06 Jan 2012 10:50:36 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language,Cookie
Content-Language: ru
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Here Request:

```
GET /community/accounts/?type=table&_=1325847040822&offset=0&limit=25&order_by=name&search=Danzanus&echo=2&id=accounts_index HTTP/1.1
Host: worldoftanks.ru
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-CSRFToken: aec8c3f844e930e61e8a1b7f2a51b175
Referer: http://worldoftanks.ru/community/accounts/
Cookie: csrftoken=aec8c3f844e930e61e8a1b7f2a51b175; __utma=1.624357332.1325795055.1325812734.1325847014.4; __utmz=1.1325795055.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); csw_popup=true; csw_top=true; __utmb=1.1.10.1325847014; __utmc=1
```

Site is http://worldoftanks.com/community/accounts/

GET request with parameters:
http://worldoftanks.ru/community/accounts/?type=table&_=1325847040822&offset=0&limit=25&order_by=name&search=Danzanus&echo=2&id=accounts_index

I need get result of search with link to user profile. Firebug(FF plugin) show this answer:

```
{"request_data":{"items":[{"account_url":"/community/accounts/4213704-Danzanus/","abbreviation":"","exp":514111,"name":"Danzanus","clan_url":"","owner":null,"wins":816,"created_at":"2011-11-29","id":4213704,"battles":1626}],"total_count":0,"filtered_count":1,"offset":0,"echo":2},"result":"success"}
```

I need only "account_url".

this code return 200 OK but answer is null:

```
 $.get("http://worldoftanks.ru/community/accounts", { type: "table", _: 1325811501451, offset: "0", limit: "25", order_by: "name", search: "Danzanus", echo: "3", id: "accounts_index" },
   function (data) {
       alert("Data Loaded: " + data);}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the response returned by the webservice you can just parse the XHR response (in the jQuery onsuccess method for instance, this is called after the Ajax call) and get the account_url. 
Otherwise, if you want to recreate the response client side you should create your JS object representing the response and then convert it in it's JSON representation. You can then call the method returning JSON (in this case **getMyObjAsJSON**) from your client script.

Here's a sample

```
function getMyObj() {
var firstname = 'Michael'
var lastname = 'Jordan'    
return  { FirstName: firstname, LastName: lastname };}  

function getMyObjAsJSON(){
 var myObj = getMyObj();

    if (myObj == null) {
        alert("obj not created");
        return;
    }

    //it converts the object in its JSON rapresentetion
    var jsonObj = $.toJSON(myObj);
return jsonObj}
```

Comment: i know, i can parse it using regex but problem is - how make GET request with this parameters and get response :)

Comment: You can parse it as a json object without a regex! When the success function on your ajax call is triggered, you get back a JSON object, not a simple string! So you will access it like items.account_url. If you don't know hout to make the call here is a sample : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/  (look at the bottom of the page).  You can't instruct the webservice to return you only the account_url unless you have full control over the code of the web service.

Comment: look, i updated topic. cant get answer... dnt know im doing wrong?

Comment: replace the url in the $.get with the full url (the one containing the requesttring) and remove the data parameters.

Comment: thanks for help, iv made it using httpWebRequest. cant submit answer, need wait 8hrs...

Comment: Hi, I don't see how the httpWebRequest helped you but glad you've made it. If any of the response you did get helped please mark them as an answer, cheers.